# Template Parameter Circular Dependency

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I do see that it has been asked here:
[C++: Template Parameter Cyclic Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143327/c-template-parameter-cyclic-dependency)

But I don't quite understand the accepted answer there.

So let me restate the question here.

Let's say I have:

```
template <class P>
class Consumer {
    P m_producer;
public:
void consume(char* data, uint32_t length) {
    if (/* some error condition */) {
        m_producer.errorCallback();
    }
}
}

template <class C>
class Producer {
    C m_consumer;
void produce() {
    char* someData;
    uint32_t length;
    m_consumer.consume(someData, length);
}
}

// Pseudocode -- not valid C++.
Producer<Consumer> c;
Consumer<Producer> p;
```

As you can see that Producer needs to call Consumer, and Consumer needs to call Producer; and both depends each other as a template parameter.

What's the best way to resolve this kind of template parameter without using any virtual class (interface)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One needs to be created before the other and you pass it as a reference to the other, storing it as a pointer.

Comment: Why is consumer a template parameter of producer? Do you really want a producer that can produce stuff only for a specific consumer? Once you drop this restriction, there is no circle anymore.

Comment: @tobi303 because i have different consumers and i would like to avoid a virtual table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any conceptual problems of this kind, the answer is: refactor, refactor, refactor. A cyclic template parameter dependency indicates a conceptual error in your business logic.

Consider what would roughly be the memory layout if this dependency where accepted:

```
// Not C++

Producer a {
  m_consumer {
    m_producer { // Not 'a', this is another producer.
      m_consumer { // With an also different consumer inside.
        // ... and it continues forever.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead, let's think about it diferently: If we need only a single consumer and a single producer joined together, it only makes sense that they're part of the same data structure. We can use the **Curiously Recurring Template Pattern** to avoid the template parameter in the producer:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Producer>
class Consumer {
  Producer& p;
public:
  bool error{false};
  Consumer(Producer& p_)
      :     p(p_)
  {}
  void consume(char* data, size_t lenght) {
    if (!data) {
      p.error_callback();
      error = true;
    }
  }
};

class Producer : public Consumer<Producer>{
public:  
  Producer()
      :    Consumer<Producer>(*this)
  {}
  Consumer<Producer>& consumer() {return *this;}
  void produce() {
    char* some_data(nullptr);
    int length{0};
    consume(some_data, length);
  }
  void error_callback() {
    std::cout << "Error\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Producer producer;
  auto& consumer = producer.consumer();
  producer.produce();
  if (consumer.error) {
    std::cout << "Got error from consumer";
  }
}
```

Let's consider the memory layout in the two first lines of `main()`:

```
// Not C++
Producer a {
  consumer { // A producer implicitly has a consumer, since it inherits from it.
    reference to a;
  }
}
reference to consumer;
```

Of course, this only solves your stated problem. But the real lesson here is: Try thinking about the memory layout you expect, and this will help you figure out how to express it in code.

Comment: Learned a lot (especially the Curiously Recurring Template although it is not what I could use in my problem, it has some interesting characteristic).  Thanks for your input!

Comment: actually, there is an interesting solution http://qscribble.blogspot.com/2008/06/circular-template-references-in-c.html Not sure whether there is a more elegant way to do so given C++11 and C++14 are available now.